# SceneKit SCNLookAtConstraint not impacting orientation

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am attempting to orientate an SCNNode towards another target node. I feel like I'm missing something, because whatever position I give to the target node, the viewer maintains the same orientation. The following code pasted into a Storyboard produces this console log consistently:

```
SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0) SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0)
```

```
func lookAtNode() {
    
    let sceneView = SCNView()
    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene
    
    let target = SCNNode()
    target.position = SCNVector3(x: 5, y: 0, z: -5)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(target)
    
    let viewer = SCNNode()
    viewer.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 5, z: 0)
    let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: target)
    //lookAt.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    viewer.constraints = [lookAt]
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(viewer)

    print(viewer.presentation.orientation, viewer.orientation)
    
}

lookAtNode()
```

The main reason I am using this as opposed to a simple lookAt (node) is because I need to prevent roll, and the isGimbalLockEnabled property provides this function if I can get this to work.

Comment: You're creating a new `SCNView` instead of using the view of your viewController?

Comment: This was just an example in a Storyboard. I’m not sure why that would make a difference. A simple .lookAt(node: works just find in this context. It just also rotates around Z.

Comment: That's because `lookAt(node:` updates the node immediately, but constraints are evaluated during the render loop. As your scene is never rendered the constraints are not applied.

Comment: @JamesP Well that explains it. Thank you so much. That’s really helpful. Just moved this into a VC, and as you say it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work. I went this the whole thing with looking at orientation values too trying to figure out why it wasn't rotating.

First, create your viewer node, then add any materials to a subnode of viewerNode (aka displayNode).  When the viewer node looksAt the target, all subnode materials will rotate with it.  A quick way to test it is just to add an SCNBox as a subnode, then you can get a visual.

Class GameType...

```
    func add(vGameType: gameTypes, vCount: Int, vPanelName: String)
    {
      name = "\(vGameType):\(vCount)"
      gameType = vGameType
      displayNode = gNodes.loadDefenseNode(vGameType: vGameType)
      node.name = "\(vGameType):\(vCount)"
      node.addChildNode(displayNode!)
      gNodes.gameNodes.addChildNode(node)
      node.isHidden = false
    }
    func setTarget()
    {
      node.constraints = []
      let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: targetNode)
      vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
      node.constraints = [vConstraint]
}
```

I know this works at least in previous versions, so if that doesn't do it, then it may be how you've initialized the scene.  Put it in a var as part of viewDidLoad() then you know everything initialized.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var SoundAction = SCNAction()
    var SoundNode = SCNNode()
    var scene = SCNScene()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Change this
        scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "MenuWinner.caf")!
        audioSource.volume = 1.0
        SoundAction = SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false)

        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc
    func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(SoundNode)
        SoundNode.runAction(SoundAction)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give this a go and see if it makes a difference. The main issue is I actually don’t care what the rendered view looks like. I’m using SceneKit to retrieve values used elsewhere. Sadly simd doesn’t provide this API.